# Android Emulator | Overdraw bug

Tags: android, android-emulator, gpu-overdraw

I have tested my application with overdraw enabled in the emulator, and once i disabled it the overdraw won't go.

Things i tried:

1. Reinstall the application in the emulator.
2. Create new emulator and run the app there.
3. Running other version of android studio (2.2 preview).
4. Turn the Overdraw On&Off again.

None of this helped.

If i try to run some other sample application, everything will work fine.

Any idea what can i do? anyone else is facing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It also happens with real device, I had to reboot my phone to get rid of overdraw.